# Display image with actual sizes onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zooming

Before posting here i was testing over 30 or so Jquery image plugins to make my images appear full width when clicked on.

the structure of the HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="whatever">
   <img id="noonecares" src="pff"></img>
</div>
```

and not

```
<a href=".."><img ></img></a>
```

I'm not talking about zooming in the photos but displaying the whole image onclick instead
I'm looking for a Jquery solution preferably.

The solutions that i've been looking into are: zoomfancy easyzoom ajaxzoom ...

Thank y'all

Comment: you mean in a new browser window

Comment: in a responsive lightbox-like popup window

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a simple inline image expander then jQuery's `toggleClass()` is perfect for that. You shrink the images to a fixed size with CSS and then toggle it with a click.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QKEVc/)

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
<div>
<img src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRvA_rqizvEgVJhJwLbpgMz7CgGwnjW5BlXHrBNzRwRXsq7O3Gi" />
</div>
```

script

```
$("div").on("click", function() {
    window.open($("img").attr("src"), "_blank", "menubar=1,resizable=1"); 
});
```

?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisbenseler/6GW6M/

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach.

```
<div class="whatever">
   <img id="noonecares" src="http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/100x75q90/21/0ss1.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

Script

```
$('.whatever').on('click','#noonecares', function(){
    window.open($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hFp6z/

UPDATE: If you want a plugin to zoom full size, then you can check [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) or [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/).

Comment: I'm looking for a plugin that does the zooming when the image is clicked on thanks

Comment: These two utilize a different html structure than the one i hereinabove described thx anyway